# laser_scan_matcher building problem

Tags: laser, ros-melodic, catkin, build, scanner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically I'm trying to get laser scanner data in world coordinates. I would like to make it possible to get the whole point cloud data with subscriber node from python code to work on it (I'm making project of detecting moving objects from laser scanner data). If any of you guys reading this post have some experience in this topic i would like to ask some more questions.

I'm new to ROS and I'm not sure if this is the right package to use in this case.
So the problem is, while I'm trying   to build package from these steps (From [THIS](https://answers.ros.org/question/197658/errors-at-catkin_make-for-laser_scan_matcher/?answer=197757?answer=197757#post-id-197757) post):

```
$ cd [indigo catkin workspace directory]
$ git clone https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools
$ sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
$ catkin_make
$ roslaunch laser_scan_matcher demo.launch
```

After running `catkin build` I receive an error saying :

```
Errors     << laser_scan_matcher:cmake /media/wojtek/48ee3ba1-28bb-493d-b2ff-de733667d003/wojtek/wstool_ws2/logs/laser_scan_matcher/build.cmake.000.log
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:415 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:593 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:21 (pkg_check_modules)


cd /media/wojtek/48ee3ba1-28bb-493d-b2ff-de733667d003/wojtek/wstool_ws2/build/laser_scan_matcher; catkin build --get-env laser_scan_matcher | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/cmake /media/wojtek/48ee3ba1-28bb-493d-b2ff-de733667d003/wojtek/wstool_ws2/src/scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher --no-warn-unused-cli -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/media/wojtek/48ee3ba1-28bb-493d-b2ff-de733667d003/wojtek/wstool_ws2/devel/.private/laser_scan_matcher -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/media/wojtek/48ee3ba1-28bb-493d-b2ff-de733667d003/wojtek/wstool_ws2/install; cd -
...............................................................................
Failed     << laser_scan_matcher:cmake               [ Exited with code 1 ]    
Failed    <<< laser_scan_matcher                     [ 5.3 seconds ]           
Finished  <<< ncd_parser                             [ 9.5 seconds ]           
_______________________________________________________________________________
Warnings   << laser_scan_sparsifier:make /media/wojtek/48ee3ba1-28bb-493d-b2ff-de733667d003/wojtek/wstool_ws2/logs/laser_scan_sparsifier/build.make.000.log
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:40:0,
                 from /media/wojtek/48ee3ba1-28bb-493d-b2ff-de733667d003/wojtek/wstool_ws2/src/scan_tools/laser_scan_sparsifier/include/laser_scan_sparsifier/laser_scan_sparsifier.h:33,
                 from /media/wojtek/48ee3ba1-28bb-493d-b2ff-de733667d003/wojtek/wstool_ws2/src/scan_tools/laser_scan_sparsifier/src/laser_scan_sparsifier.cpp:30:
/media/wojtek/48ee3ba1-28bb-493d-b2ff-de733667d003/wojtek/wstool_ws2/src/scan_tools/laser_scan_sparsifier/src/laser_scan_sparsifier.cpp: In constructor ‘scan_tools::LaserScanSparsifier::LaserScanSparsifier(ros::NodeHandle, ros::NodeHandle)’:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/console.h:348:176: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘,’ in format [-Wformat=]
     ::ros::console::print(filter, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.logger_, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.level_, __FILE__, __LINE__, __ROSCONSOLE_FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__)
                                                                                                                                                                                ^
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/console.h:351:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION_WITH_FILTER’
     ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION_WITH_FILTER(NULL, __VA_ARGS__)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/console.h:387:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION’
       ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION(__VA_ARGS__); \
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/console.h:572:35: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG_COND’
 #define ROS_LOG(level, name, ...) ROS_LOG_COND(true, level, name, __VA_ARGS__)
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosconsole/macros_generated.h:266:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG’
 #define ROS_FATAL(...) ROS_LOG(::ros::console::levels::Fatal, ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME, __VA_ARGS__)
                        ^~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/assert.h:134:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_FATAL’
       ROS_FATAL(__VA_ARGS__); \
       ^~~~~~~~~
/media/wojtek/48ee3ba1-28bb-493d-b2ff-de733667d003/wojtek/wstool_ws2/src/scan_tools/laser_scan_sparsifier/src/laser_scan_sparsifier.cpp:45:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_ASSERT_MSG’
   ROS_ASSERT_MSG(step_ > 0,
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/console.h:348:176: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     ::ros::console::print(filter, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.logger_, __rosconsole_define_location__loc.level_, __FILE__, __LINE__, __ROSCONSOLE_FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__)
                                                                                                                                                                                ^
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/console.h:351:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION_WITH_FILTER’
     ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION_WITH_FILTER(NULL, __VA_ARGS__)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/console.h:387:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION’
       ROSCONSOLE_PRINT_AT_LOCATION(__VA_ARGS__); \
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/console.h:572:35: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG_COND’
 #define ROS_LOG(level, name, ...) ROS_LOG_COND(true, level, name, __VA_ARGS__)
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosconsole/macros_generated.h:266:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG’
 #define ROS_FATAL(...) ROS_LOG(::ros::console::levels::Fatal, ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME, __VA_ARGS__)
                        ^~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/assert.h:134:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_FATAL’
       ROS_FATAL(__VA_ARGS__); \
       ^~~~~~~~~
/media/wojtek/48ee3ba1-28bb-493d-b2ff-de733667d003/wojtek/wstool_ws2/src/scan_tools/laser_scan_sparsifier/src/laser_scan_sparsifier.cpp:45:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_ASSERT_MSG’
   ROS_ASSERT_MSG(step_ > 0,
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The rest of the packages is being built successfully.

```
Finished  <<< laser_scan_sparsifier                  [ 10.5 seconds ]          
Finished  <<< polar_scan_matcher                     [ 11.2 seconds ]          
Finished  <<< laser_scan_splitter                    [ 12.1 seconds ]          
Finished  <<< scan_to_cloud_converter                [ 15.9 seconds ]          
Finished  <<< laser_ortho_projector                  [ 23.7 seconds
```

I work on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and ROS Melodic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337330/laser_scan_matcher-building-problem/) by [asbird](https://answers.ros.org/users/49167/asbird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2019-11-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-11**:
You're trying to build a package that was last released in Kinetic under Melodic. It's not uncommon to run into issues in such cases.

There appears to be an open issue about this already though, see: [ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools#63](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools/issues/63).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following works for me in a `ros:melodic` Docker image (`docker run -it --rm ros:melodic`):

```
# activate main ROS install
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash

# update local indices
sudo apt update
rosdep update

# catkin-tools supports workspaces with 'mixed' build types, (ie:
# catkin and non-catkin packages). We could also use catkin_make_isolated.
sudo apt install python-catkin-tools

# create workspace (skip if you already have one)
mkdir -p $HOME/catkin_ws/src
cd $HOME/catkin_ws

# clone all sources
git clone https://github.com/AndreaCensi/csm.git src/csm
git clone https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools.git src/scan_tools

# install all dependencies (note: not adding '-y' here, so you'll have to
# accept all installation commands manually)
rosdep install --from-paths $HOME/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src

# build the workspace (or: catkin_make_isolated)
catkin build

# activate the workspace
source devel/setup.bash
```

at this point you should be able to use the packages from `ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools`.

Inspired by the comments on [ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools#63](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools/issues/63).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-11**:
Note that this is essentially the same process as in #q252478, but with a manual `git clone` of `csm`, as that has not been released for Melodic (but seems to build OK).

**Comment by [asbird](https://answers.ros.org/users/49167/asbird/) on 2019-11-11**:
Ok it worked thank you @gvdhoorn
Could you contact me via email zefirq97@gmail.com ? I would like to ask you few questions to not spam the forum. Of course if you don't mind.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-11**:
No, I won't contact you. Any question you may have should be posted here on ROS Answers.

**Comment by [asbird](https://answers.ros.org/users/49167/asbird/) on 2019-11-11**:
@gvdhoorn So I'll ask the same question I've asked at the beginning. I wan't to apply transform to the laser scanner data, to give to the point cloud world coordinates. Can i achieve that with scan_tools ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-11**:
You should post that as a new question. Don't post follow-up questions in comments under accepted answers. Comments have very limited visibility.